# Best way to communicate from a UserControl to the hosting PhoneApplicationPage?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-phone

What's the best (as in design wise most elegant) way to communicate from a `UserControl` to the `PhoneApplicationPage` that hosts it? Say I have a button in my `UserControl`, pressing it does something that takes a while and while the `UserControl` is working, I want to show an overlay on my `Page`.

I know I can use `events` and `EventHandlers` to subscribe for events on my `Page` that the `UserControl` fires. So my question is basically, is this really the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an event is definitely the best and recommended way to handle this situation. Have a look to built-in controls, every communication to another control or parent is handled through events. Communication from the control to the host should be optional and non-intrusive, that's what events have been designed for.

Comment: There are many reasons to hate events for, but thanks for clarifying my initial thoughts. Let's hope Microsoft comes up with something more elegant and modern in upcoming .NET releases.